# How to upgrade external dll?

Tags: .net, dll

I recently discovered a bug in NHibernate project & reported & fixed the source locally, now I've got a newer nhibernate.dll

In the Umbraco project I've replaced the original reference with the newer DLL file. When I rebuild the project I got many errors like below:

> Error 30  The type 'NHibernate.Bytecode.ICollectionTypeFactory' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'. C:\NET\vhosts\umbraco_61ea7a8b6526\Source\Libraries\Umbraco.Framework.Persistence.NHibernate\OrmConfig\MsSqlCe4Configuration.cs 18  18  Umbraco.Framework.Persistence.NHibernate

In 90s it was easy as overwriting the dll with newer one. How can I upgrade that dll in 2012s?

Comment: In 90s, overwriting DLLs like this was what caused [a lot of problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). Do you have some other reference that depends on that DLL that you did not rebuild? What are the version numbers of the old and new version?

Comment: Version numbers are same but mine dll doesn't contain PublicKeyToken information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have some assembly that you did not rebuild against your version of NHibernate.dll. If, for some reason, you can't rebuild it, you can try signing your version of NHibernate.dll using the same private key as the original.

That private key, NHibernate.snk, is available in [the NHibernate repository](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src).

Comment: Oh thanks, I already got the .snk file but I didn't know it's a public file. Now I'll sign & test